# Rails, "standard" jQuery Ajax versus remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

For purpose of intro to question, user in application can *vote up / vote down* on submitted article. I defined two non-restful routes via:

```
get 'vote_up/:storage_id' => 'home#vote_up', :as => 'vote_up'
get 'vote_down/:storage_id' => 'home#vote_down', :as => 'vote_down'

<%= link_to image_tag("up1.png"), vote_up_path(post.storage_id), :class => "vote_up" %>
<%= link_to image_tag("down1.png"), vote_down_path(post.storage_id), :class => "vote_down", :remote => true %>
```

So first link will not use `:remote => true`, second will.

When i say "standard" Ajax, which i will use for vote_up action i mean on following:

# *inside home controller*

```
def vote_up
  storage = Storage.find(params[:storage_id])
  storage.vote.count += 1
  storage.vote.save

  render :json => {:votes => storage.vote.count, :id => params[:storage_id]}
end
```

So when user click on vote_up button, browser will send following ajax request:
# *assets/javascript/home.js*

```
$(function() {
  $('.vote_up').click(function() {
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      var selector = "#like_counter-" + data.id;
      $(selector).html(data.votes);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

**My question is what is difference between this way and way with `:remote=>true` which is described bellow. From technical view, nothing? I can assume only that `:remote => true` is preferred because it is more 'rails oriented'?**

# *inside home controller*

```
def vote_down
    @storage = Storage.find(params[:storage_id])

    @storage.vote.count -= 1
    @storage.vote.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

# *views/home/vote_down.js.erb*

```
$(function() {
    var selector = "#like_counter-" + '<%= @storage.id %>';
    $(selector).html('<%= @storage.vote.count %>');
});
```

In all examples, selector is span element holding votes count per each article(storage).

Comment: `remote: true` lets Rails deal with the Javascript (Ajax) functions, no need to maintain these functions, will "always" work, and a lot less code to write (which reduce the potential of errors). The "manual" way is more "granular", you can control more stuff about what's happening, but it takes time to maintain/update it. -- In most cases, `remote: true` is sufficient, and when you want something more precise, use a manual ajax call via jQuery.

Comment: Rails `:remote` is true [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), which is extremely beneficial, as it means it will adapt to changes in JS coding standards, as well as ensuring your own code is clean